# AWS API Gateway with EC2 Api backend

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Im trying to use and ec2 api backend and not exposing it to public. I want to put api gayeway on top of it. What options do i have? Is it just proxy option in api gateway? If it's that how can I protect my API backend?

If i use client side certs it doesn't protect me against DOS attacks and stuff. Im hoping there is better way to do this.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581698/how-to-config-the-api-gateway-for-the-service-deployed-in-private-subnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately client side certs is the only option available at the current time. VPC support is on our roadmap, but I can't commit to a time table as to when this would be available.