# How to config the api gateway for the service deployed in private subnet?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I deployed a web service in my private subnet without ELB in public subnet.

Now I want to expose it to public. Can I use API gateway as the http proxy

to make it public?

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 10):

The service has to be public for API Gateway to be able to connect to it. You can use SSL Client certs to restrict access to only API Gateway. Otherwise, API Gateway would not be a good solution to your issue.

**Update:** You can now configure API Gateway to access resources inside a VPC using [VPC Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html).

Comment: +1 from the API Gateway team. You're exactly right. Here's a link to the SSL client cert docs -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: Another option would be a simple API Key (say, a random hex string) injected into the the Request Headers on API Gateway and verified on the your backend

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Mark B's excellent answer, you could also consider using a Lambda function as a proxy.

API Gateway -> Lambda -> ELB

You can [configure Lambda to access VPC resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/). Lambda would have to buffer the entire result before returning it, so this would slow down large responses.